# Set default value on empty text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I generated a User model for devise and the respective devise views. Then I added a "school" field to the database. Imagine that we're in the edit view(/users/edit). How can I set a default value for school if the user leaves the "school" text_field empty?

Comment: can you post your `update` action?

Comment: i know m bit late but you can simply set the default value in migration, add_column :users, :school, :string, :default => "foobar"

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais Yes, I tried that but it only worked for the first time. If the user edited his/her profile and left the school text_field blank the DB would update it with a blank field. The before_save method did the trick ;)

Comment: @pluralism the default in the migration will work when the value is sent as nil. The reason this doesn't work is because when you submit the form you aren't submitting nil but an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a before save

```
before_save :set_school

def set_school
  self.school = "my school" if self.school.blank?
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe this was that simple!

Answer (score 2):

you can create a writer for this eg:----

suppose field name is school

put this in your model

```
def school=(value)
  if value.blank?
    write_attribute :school, 'default school'
  else
    write_attribute :school, value
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `after_initialize` to set default vaules:

```
  after_initialize do
    self.school = "awesome school"
  end
```